# How can I switch windows without a history of which window was last accessed?

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, application-switcher

Hitting alt-tab repeatedly toggles between the two most recently used windows.  I would like to be able to hit key stroke that will always move me to the next window in a list.  I want to map this key to a key on my mouse, so the alt-tab-tab-tab-etc. method won't work for me.